# Silverlight : Issue with Childwindow and navigation framework

Tags: silverlight, frameworks, navigation, childwindow

could someone help me with childwindow and Navigation?

I created a childwindow from code and set its content as

```
ChildWindow CW = new ChildWindow();
CW.Content = new MainPageMenu(param1);
```

Here "MainPageMenu" itself  is a Silverlight  Page with a "navigation:Frame"

In the constructor, i navigate to various pages according to "param1" .

As i navigate to the desired page , the ie address bar shows the updated uri.

Should it show that? as the page is navigated in a childwindow......?

This works fine for first time. Once i close the childwindow and reopen with diff "param1" to navigate to other page

it never gets navigated..!!! it shows the same page as navigated to for the first call...

there is no error at  line  -

```
this.ContentFrame.Navigate(u);
```

in the constructor.

Is this a bug in navigation framework or i am supposed to something else to achieve this ?

Please help.

Comment: I managed to resolve the issue using JournalOwnership property of the navigation frame used for navigation.

Answer (score 1):

I see you already figured out that `JournalOwnership` is th key here.  But just for a bit more background so this is less magic and more algorithm, here's how the Navigation Framework figures out whether to integrate with the browser journal, based on what `Frame.JournalOwnership` is set to.

`JournalOwnership.Automatic` (the default) - if the `Frame` is a "top level" `Frame`, it will navigate with the browser journal.  If it's not, it won't.  "Top level" means that if it walks up the visual tree it does not find any other `Frame` along the way.

`JournalOwnership.OwnsJournal` - the `Frame` will always own its own journal and not attempt to interact with the browser's journal.

`JournalOwnership.UsesParentJournal` - the `Frame` will always integrate with the browser.  If it is not a top-level `Frame` this causes an Exception to be thrown.

So what's interesting about ChildWindow is that when `Frame` walks up the visual tree to see if it's a "top-level" `Frame`, it won't find one (because `Popup` is not rooted in the visual tree in the same way, and `ChildWindow` uses a `Popup`).  Hence, it will think it's top-level (which may not really be correct in this case, but what else could it do?) so it will integrate with the browser journal.